# C++ nested class methods

Tags: c++, class, oop, templates, abstract-class

I wanted to create a structure similar to this:

```
template <typename W>
class Graph {
public:
    struct Vertex {
        std::vector<typename Graph<W>::Vertex> next() {
            return GetNext((*this));
        }
    };
    virtual std::vector<typename Graph<W>::Vertex> GetNext(Vertex v) = 0;
};
```

(don't look at missing fields etc.)

I've tried something like this but it gives all kinds of errors, including syntax errors or "unable to instantiate" even thought I try to instantiate derived class which has GetNext overriden.

Question is: is that structure even allowed in C++ and how to implement it correctly?

Comment: Inside `Vertex` (and so inside `Graph<W>`), you can simply use `Vertex` instead of `typename Graph<W>::Vertex`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only problem with your code is that you call `GetNext` from `Vertex` but `Vertex` has no `GetNext` member function.

If you want to call a method of `Graph` from `Vertex`, then you need a `Graph` variable to call it on, e.g. a member variable:

```
struct Vertex {
    Graph& graph;

    std::vector<typename Graph<W>::Vertex> next() {
        return graph.GetNext(*this);
    }
};
```